# proc transpose using SPDE takes ~60x longer to run than v9 library

Tags: sas

I've been moving all of my datasets into SPDE libraries because I've experienced wonderful performance gains in everything. Everything until running proc transpose. This takes ~60x longer to execute on the SPDE dataset than the same dataset stored in normal v9 library. The data sets is sorted by item_id. It is being read/written to the same library.

Does anyone have an idea why this is the case? Am I missing something important about SPDE and Proc Transpose not playing well together?

**SPDE Libary**

```
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   proc transpose data = smplus.links_response_mechanism out = smplus.response_mechanism (drop = _NAME_) 
prefix = rm_;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   by item_id;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   id lookup_code;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   var x;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   run;

NOTE: There were 5866747 observations read from the data set SMPLUS.LINKS_RESPONSE_MECHANISM.
NOTE: The data set SMPLUS.RESPONSE_MECHANISM has 3209353 observations and 14 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set SMPLUS.RESPONSE_MECHANISM decreased size by 37.98 percent.
NOTE: PROCEDURE TRANSPOSE used (Total process time):
      real time           28:27.63
      cpu time            28:34.64
```

**V9 Library**

```
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   proc transpose data = mplus.links_response_mechanism out = mplus.response_mechanism (drop = _NAME_) 
prefix = rm_;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   by item_id;
68                                                         The SAS System                             02:00 Thursday, August 8, 2013

MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   id lookup_code;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   var x;
MPRINT(XMLIMPORT_VANTAGE):   run;

NOTE: There were 5866747 observations read from the data set MPLUS.LINKS_RESPONSE_MECHANISM.
NOTE: The data set MPLUS.RESPONSE_MECHANISM has 3209353 observations and 14 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set MPLUS.RESPONSE_MECHANISM decreased size by 27.60 percent. 
      Compressed is 32271 pages; un-compressed would require 44572 pages.
NOTE: PROCEDURE TRANSPOSE used (Total process time):
      real time           28.76 seconds
      cpu time            28.79 seconds
```

Comment: A few things to check: make sure your SPDE library isn't running low on space, in particular in the utility location.  Make sure this is repeatable.  I don't know of any particular restrictions with SPDE and PROC TRANSPOSE, but if both of those two things aren't an issue I think a support ticket with SAS would be a good idea; it's possible there are some issues.

Comment: Also, you should include some details about your SPDE library - how many disks does it span, etc.  Perhaps just post an anonymized version of the libname statement?

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me that there is some issue with PROC TRANSPOSE and SPDE.  Here's a simple SSCCE, which has significant differences; not as significant as yours, but to some extent that may be a factor of this being on a desktop with not particularly substantial performance tuning in the first place.  Sounds like a call to SAS tech support is in order.

```
libname spdelib spde 'c:\temp\SPDE Main' 
    datapath=('c:\temp\SPDE Data' 'd:\temp\SPDE Data')
    indexpath=('d:\temp\SPDE Index')
    partsize=512;

libname mainlib 'c:\temp\';


data mainlib.bigdata;
do ID = 1 to 1500000;
  do _varn=1 to 10;
    varname=cats("Var_",_varn);
    vardata=ranuni(7);
    output;
  end;
end;
run;
data  spdelib.bigdata;
do ID = 1 to 1500000;
  do _varn=1 to 10;
    varname=cats("Var_",_varn);
    vardata=ranuni(7);
    output;
  end;
end;
run;
*These data steps take roughly the same amount of time, around 30 seconds each;

proc transpose data=spdelib.bigdata out=spdelib.transdata;
by id;
id varname;
var vardata;
run;
*Run a few times, this takes around 3 to 4 minutes, with 1.5 minutes CPU time;

proc transpose data=mainlib.bigdata out=mainlib.transdata;
by id;
id varname;
var vardata;
run;
*Run a few times, this takes around 30 to 45 seconds, with 20 seconds CPU time;
```

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that READING is the main problem.  Swapping MAIN and SPDE libraries about, read from main write to spde is around the same efficiency as main to main; read from spde write to main is slow.

Answer (score 1):

There have been known issues with SPDE and proc compare in the past (not multi-threading), at least up to version 4.1.  What version are you using? (can be seen in the “!install/logs” folder).

This is definitely something to [raise with SAS support](http://support.sas.com/ctx/supportform/createForm), to "speed" things along I would recommend submitting a log with the following options:

```
proc setinit noalias; run; 
proc options; run; 
%put _ALL_; 
options fullstimer msglevel=i;
```

Also:

```
options spdedebug='DA_TRACEIO_OCR CJNL=Trace.txt';
```

(The CJNL option simply routes the trace message output to a text file)

In the meantime, you may be able to take advantage of some of the following SPD specific options:

http://support.sas.com/kb/11/349.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs when PROC TRANSPOSE is used with BY-processing on compressed datasets. SAS is forced to read the same block of rows repeatedly decompressing them every time until all the records are fully sorted.

Set Compress=No option and it will work. See the log below, one program has Compress=yes and the other Compress=no, the former was 56 minutes vs .5 seconds.

```
OPTIONS COMPRESS=YES;

50         **tranpose from spde to spde;
51         proc transpose data=spdelib.balancewalkoutput out=spdelib.spdelib_to_spdelib;
52           var metric ;
53           by balancewalk facility_id isretained isexisting isicaapnpl monthofmaturity vintage;
54         run;

NOTE: There were 10000000 observations read from the data set SPDELIB.BALANCEWALKOUTPUT.
NOTE: The data set SPDELIB.SPDELIB_TO_SPDELIB has 160981 observations and 74 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set SPDELIB.SPDELIB_TO_SPDELIB decreased size by 69.96 percent.
NOTE: PROCEDURE TRANSPOSE used (Total process time):
      real time           56:58.54
      user cpu time       52:03.65
      system cpu time     4:03.00
      memory              19028.75k
      OS Memory           34208.00k
      Timestamp           09/16/2019 06:19:55 PM
      Step Count                        9  Switch Count  22476
      Page Faults                       0
      Page Reclaims                     4056
      Page Swaps                        0
      Voluntary Context Switches        142316
      Involuntary Context Switches      5726
      Block Input Operations            88
      Block Output Operations           569200


OPTIONS COMPRESS=NO;

50         **tranpose from spde to spde;
51         proc transpose data=spdelib.balancewalkoutput out=spdelib.spdelib_to_spdelib;
52           var metric ;
53           by balancewalk facility_id isretained isexisting isicaapnpl monthofmaturity vintage;

18                                                         The SAS System                           16:04 Monday, September 16, 2019

54         run;

NOTE: There were 10000000 observations read from the data set SPDELIB.BALANCEWALKOUTPUT.
NOTE: The data set SPDELIB.SPDELIB_TO_SPDELIB has 160981 observations and 74 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE TRANSPOSE used (Total process time):
      real time           26.73 seconds
      user cpu time       14.52 seconds
      system cpu time     11.99 seconds
      memory              13016.71k
      OS Memory           27556.00k
      Timestamp           09/16/2019 04:13:06 PM
      Step Count                        9  Switch Count  24827
      Page Faults                       0
      Page Reclaims                     2662
      Page Swaps                        0
      Voluntary Context Switches        162653
      Involuntary Context Switches      1678
      Block Input Operations            96
      Block Output Operations           1510040
```